# Not able to inject external JavaScript library to React program

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My use case is to integrate headwayapp.co to my React application.

I am trying to inject js via react component

The code of headwayapp is as follows to inject

```
<script src="//cdn.headwayapp.co/widget.js"></script>
<script>
  var config = {
    selector: ".CHANGE_THIS",
    account: "ACCOUNT_ID"
  };
  Headway.init(config);
</script>
```

Though I tried multiples way to inject code into the react.

In most cases I am not able to understand how to handle the line

```
Headway.init(config);
```

as react is not able to understand what is Headway variable ?

Comment: The component that contains that selector needs to mount before you intialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject that code into your react app, you could simply place those script tags in your `index.html` file of your react app. Then you will be able to access the `Headway` variable in any of your react components like so: `window.Headway`

So basically, the code from `http://cdn.headwayapp.co/widget.js` will be loaded into your app at the place, where you put your script tags. That code is declaring `Headway` as a global variable, and global variables are living in the `window object` of your app. It does not matter if it is a react app or not.